# 2 onclick events to refresh and redirect to square app

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am trying to create 2 onclick events one to refresh a javascript function and the other to direct to square app. the problem is that I need to refresh the browser for the updated amount to show up on square app. The other option I can do , is to refresh the browser only once and then direct to square using "Payment" button. I can go with either option.

```html
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-flat" onclick='myFunction(); location.href="square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));'>
```

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
  setInterval(function(){ loadItems(); }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: sorry its not clear, i dont understant what you want to do.. if you click on button, the program executes myfunction then it go to href....so...could you precise what you want?

Comment: yes, I want to execute the function and go to href. the execution is not doing anything so I don't know if the code is correct. But also, I have another option which is to refresh the page only once then redirect to the link using the payment button. I can't seem to find any code to help me refresh the browser only once then redirect to square app once I click payment button.

Comment: the problem, right now when I add a service, I have to refresh the page before clicking "payment", for the correct value to be passed to square app.